# TextMate recover after kernel panic

Tags: recovery, textmate

I was working on an unsaved file when the kernel suddenly got a panic attack. I have the 'Save files when focus is lost" checkbox checked, and I frequently switched between textmate and the browser, so plenty of oppurtunities to autosave there. I don't see any autosaved documents in my 'recently opened documents'. Is there any chance I can get my work back?

Comment: Did you look in the terminal if there is a hidden files  that may be a autosave of you document. `ls -a` lists all files including the hidden ones.

Comment: I have hidden files visible in the finder. In which directory should I be looking?

Comment: Are you using the OpenSource version of TextMate, if not which version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

The file was located in:
**~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Session/**

This is for the OpenSource version of TextMate 2.0-alpha-9487, on osx Mountain Lion 1.8.5

Comment: Which Textmate version and which OSX? I know the OP didn't specify his, but it would be useful anyway to specify yours.

Comment: @Lohoris that is why I asked about his version of TextMate.